# Issues using plugin with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I am using [Alaxo's Acl plugin](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0) in cakephp. My cakephp version is  2.3.9. I get the following error due to which I am not able to proceed:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: C:\wamp\www\amigo\app\Plugin\Acl\Controller\Component\AclManagerComponent.php 
Line: 227
```

Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the line of code you're (probably - the code should be in the question) referring to is effectively `$this->Acl->Aco->find('all', array('recursive' => -1));` you should check what `$this->Acl` is, and why `..->Aco` is not a model object.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry, did not understand clearly. Can you please slightly elaborate , so that I can debug the code the way you suggest and update the result.